# Error using built-in dialog box "xldialogApplyNames"

Tags: vba, excel, dialog

I wanted to use the named built-in dialog box in Excel via VBA. I learned to use it like this [here](https://www.excel-inside.de/vba-loesungen/sonstiges/306-uebersicht-aller-integrierten-excel-dialoge).

That is working for many named built-in boxes, but not for `ApplyNames`. All arguments are optional, so that is not the problem. I also tried to define a `boolean` variable and say `variable = dialogbox` so that the box (outcome is a `boolean` as far as I understood it) has something to write the result in. But that didn't work either.

My code looks like this:

```
Public Sub Box()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogApplyNames).Show
End Sub
```

The error which occurs is:

> Laufzeitfehler 1004: Objekt- oder Anwendungsdefinierter Fehler"

*or in english (hope I translated it correctly):*

> "runtime error 1004: error of object or application"

Thank you in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested and I can reproduce the error if the active workbook does not contain any range names. As soon as you add one the dialog is displayed. So:

```
Public Sub Box()
    If ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count >0 Then    
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogApplyNames).Show
    End If
End Sub
```